# How to use the OBS-ndi plugin (4.9.1) with OBS (25.0.3) ; Ubuntu studio (20.04.2)

Tags: plugins, obs-studio

OBS (Open Broadcasting Sofware) seems to work well as natively installed in Ubuntu Studio.
I like !

I now try to use the OBS-ndi plugin, in order to team up two computers for streaming. For that to work, the said plugin has to be present in both Ubuntus, both computers.

One of these computer used to be a MAC desktop and now using Ubuntu studio, version 20.04.2. ;  graphic interface Xfce 4.14

The other is an HP tower using Ubuntu Studio 21.04,  ;  graphic interface KDE Plasma 5.21.4

From the information I gathered here and there, the current versions of OBS integrated in Ubuntu Studio should include the ndi plugin ... but it is not clear to me ... maybe it is for the Windows or OsX versions, not for the Ubuntu environment ...
Someone knows ?

The ndi-plugin adds some tools to OBS. Among others, OBS with the ndi plugin should offer a ndi source. It is not the case for my two OBS installations even after trying to copy and extract the
libndi4_4.5.1-1_amd64.deb
and
obs-ndi_4.9.1-1_amd64.deb
in the /usr/share/obs/obs-plugins folder

So ... In my understanding OBS-ndi plugin was not in the OBS versions at first and I failed when trying to install it.
Any suggestions for the installation and testing of that plugin ?
Merci !

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you solved your problem. Please don't put SOLVED, FIXED, RESOLVED etc. in the question title and the solution inside the question. Please click on the **Answer your own question button** below and write the solution as an answer. Then after the required waiting time accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check button ✓ and turn it green ✅. This will help others. See the [site help](https://askubuntu.com/help) for how to answer questions in this site.

Answer (score 1):

The ndi plugin now works fine after installation on both computers.
The sudo dpkg -i *.deb performed while in the Download folder did the installation.
Thanks